# Evaluate multiple conditions in Excel and return an incremental value if true

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I've been searching the web for about 3 hours now and decided it was time to ask how to do the following:

```
=IF

('SHEETNAME'!A:A1000)="SALESMAN"

AND

('SHEETNAME'!B:B1000)="WON"

THEN

INCREASE FORMULA CELL VALUE BY ONE
```

So basically I'm trying to calculate how many jobs were won by each salesman based on information entered on another sheet.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken you are trying to count that how many  Salesman has Won the job. And if you upload portion of sample data will help us to understand the issue in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS('SHEETNAME'!A1:A1000,"SALESMAN",'SHEETNAME'!B1:B1000,"WON")
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I was unaware you could add an "S" to the COUNTIF function but that did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of salespeople in Column `C`, insert the following formula in column `D`

```
=COUNTIFS(A$1:A$100,C1,B$1:B$1000,"WON")
```

Then populate down for each sales person

[image]

Comment: The OP's criteria are Salesman & Won , you formula needs correction !

Answer (score -2):

You can count the Salesman and Won by using this formula also:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheetname!A1:A1000="SALESMAN")*(Sheetname!B1:B1000="WON"))
```